# How do I get emacs to indent other things like it indents define?

Tags: emacs, scheme, racket

So Emacs is pretty good at editing Scheme/Racket/Lisp code.  One good thing it does is when you type code like:

```
(define (make-position-table)
  (for/list ([i (in-range 256)])
            `()))
```

It does a very clever thing and indents the second line to two columns.  Now the third line it does what it does with all lisp code and indents that to align all the arguments.

How do I customize Emacs so that it indents the third line as though I was introducing a new body.  What I'd like is:

```
(define (make-position-table)
  (for/list ([i (in-range 256)])
    `()))
```

I'm guessing this is possible and that I just haven't figured out the arcane Emacs variable to set.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add this to your `.emacs` file:

```
(put 'for/list 'scheme-indent-function 1)
```

See also a [hacked version of scheme mode](https://github.com/elibarzilay/eliemacs/raw/master/extras/scheme.el) that does many more racket-isms.

Answer (score 5):

I believe `(put 'for/list 'scheme-indent-function 'defun)` should do what you want.

Repeat for other symbols.  My .emacs includes

```
(mapc (lambda (sym) (put sym 'scheme-indent-function 'defun))
      (list 'for 'for/list 'for/and 'for/or
            'match 'case 'syntax-parse 'test-suite 'test-case
            'define-syntax-rule 'match-let 'match-let*))
```

from the days when I was dabbling in PLT Scheme.

Comment: Using `defun` is different from `1`: try a newline right after the opening keyword and you'll see how it works.  (In addition, Racket has things like `for/fold` that have two special forms.)